# How do I call shared directive's method in Angular2 RC5 typescript?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have custom directive in my code that several components should consume. I registered it in my app.module and thus can use it in my templates.

But my problem is that I see no way to call this directive's methods from components code as it doesn't import and register it in `directives: []` any longer?

E.g.
Here when I don't share the directive it is used like

```
    import { Modal } from '../bootstrap';
    @Component({
        templateUrl: '.....html',
        directives: [Modal]
    })
    export class MyComponent {
            constructor(private modal: Modal) {
            this.modal.show();
        }
    }
```

but when I extracted these components into the separate modules and moved this directive to a shared module, `import ..` and `directives: [...]` are gone and I cannot have `private modal: Modal` injected to call its method `show`. If I keep them, I get `Error: Type Modal is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ...` error message.

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. I don't see how calling shared directives code and adding them to `directives: []` is related.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: You don't provide or inject components, only services (except maybe if you want a reference to the parent in the child).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to `[providers]` in your AppModule:

`providers: [Modal]`

Then you need to import that service in component that should consume it and it will work, there is no need to add it as directives, for example:

`import { Modal } from '../bootstrap';`

You can then add it to constructor:

`constructor (private modal: Modal)`

Now you can use that service:

`this.modal.show()`

Edit:

Updated the answer to match the code you provided.

Comment: I have several modules that depend on app.module and I need this directive in all of them. I tried to create a shared module that would provide this directive but I've got Error: Type Modal is part of the declarations of 2 modules: error...

Comment: Remove Modal from your main module and just leave it in your shared module, that may be the problem. You should provide more code.